# objective-c Add to/Edit .plist file

Tags: objective-c, info.plist, root.plist

Does writeToFile:atomically, add data to an existing .plist? Is it possible to modify a value in a .plist ? SHould the app be recompiled to take effect the change?

I have a custom .plist list in my app. The structure is as below:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>MyTitle</string>
    <key>Measurement</key>
    <dict>
        <key>prop1</key>
        <real>28.86392</real>
        <key>prop2</key>
        <real>75.12451</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Distance</key>
    <dict>
        <key>prop3</key>
        <real>37.49229</real>
        <key>prop4</key>
        <real>58.64502</real>
    </dict>
</dict>
</array>
```

The array tag holds multiple  items with same structure. I need to add items to the existing .plist. Is that possible? I can write a UIView to do just that, if so.

*EDIT - OK, I just tried to writetofile hoping it would atleast overwrite if not add to it. Strangely, the following code selects different path while reading and writing.

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

The .plist file is in my project. I can read from it. When I write to it, it is creating a .plist file and saving it in my /users/.../library/! Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the `plist` that comes with application is assumed `read only` - it is inside the app bundle.

Any updates are stored in user specific directory, so that every user would have their own specific modifications.

Comment: Absolutely correct. You should never write to any files in your application's bundle. Users without admin privileges generally don't have permission to do this. If you need to store persistent data, store it in `~/Library/Application Support` or use `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can create and write your own .plist file. By `NSArray *arrayPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *userFile=[[arrayPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/whatever.plist"];` , you can write/edit it.